# I have a response of json body from a login API . I made a model class for that json. Now how to use it in my pages to fetch data?

Tags: json, flutter, api, model

I have logged in from a api . Then i got a response of json . I can fetch data from login to homepage . For that i created a constructor in homepage and pass it in Login page where i made navigator for the homepage . But i know it's not good practice to fetch data like it. using model class is more smart way. I added my code here of login, homepage and model . Now my data can only communicate between these two page . But i need to fetch data to another pages too.

login.dart

```
    import 'package:api_login/model/response_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import '../sharePreference.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';


class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {

var notification ;
  bool isprocesscomplete = false;
  TextEditingController _userController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String BaseUrl = "my url";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 770,
             color:  Colors. lightBlue,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 100, 20, 20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [

                Text(
                  "Login",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 220,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _userController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Username"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_userController.text == "" ||
                          _passwordController.text == "") {
                        final snackBar = SnackBar(
                            content: Text("Enter Username and Password"));
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      } else {
                        signIn(_userController.text, _passwordController.text);
                      }
                    },
                    child: ProgressButton(),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Forgot password"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget ProgressButton() {
    if (isprocesscomplete != false) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white));
    } else {
      return new Text(
        "Sign In",
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 15.0,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void signIn(String username, String password) async {
    setState(() {
      isprocesscomplete = true;
    });
    var response = await http.post(BaseUrl,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode({
          "username": username,
          "password": password,
        }));

    Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
    notification = value["notifications"];
    // print('Response ${response.body}');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        ///You don't need it but it will be cool for show progress dialgo for 4 second then redirect even if we get reslut
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
          // 5s over make it false
          setState(() {
            isprocesscomplete = true;
          });
        });
        Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
        print('Response ${response.body}');
        SharedPrefrence().setToken(value['api_token'].toString());
        SharedPrefrence().setName(value['user_name']);
        SharedPrefrence().setUserId(value['user_id'].toString());

        ///This is used when user loged in you can set this true,
        ///next time you open you need to check loginc in main.dart or splashscreen if this is true if it is true then
        ///redirect to home page it is false then redirect to Login page
        ///When you logout the app make sure you set this as false like "SharedPrefrence().setLoggedIn(false);"
        SharedPrefrence().setLoggedIn(true);

        ///Redirect to Home page
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => HomePage(
                                      user_name: value['user_name'],
                                      api_token: value['api_token'],
                                      notification: notification,
                                     // payment: payment ,
                                    )),
                                ModalRoute.withName("/login"));

      } catch (e) {
        e.toString();
        final snackBar =
        SnackBar(
            content: Text("something wrong,Try again "),
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        );
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }
    } else {
      var message = value['error'];
      final snackBar = SnackBar( backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[700],
          content: Text(message.toString()),
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating, );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }
}
```

homepage.dart

```
    import 'package:api_login/model/response_model.dart';
import 'package:api_login/pages/details.dart';
import 'package:api_login/pages/settingPage.dart';
import 'package:api_login/widget/neumorphsm.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../sharePreference.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'login.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 final payment;
  final count ;
  String user_name;
  final api_token;
  final user_id ;
  final payment_id;
  final  List<dynamic> notification ;
  // List data ;
  HomePage({ this.user_name, this.api_token , this.user_id, @required this.notification ,
             this.count, this.payment, this.payment_id});


  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  String arrayLength ;
  String nametoprint;
  String tokentoprint;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future name = SharedPrefrence().getName();
    name.then((data) async {
      nametoprint = data;
      print(nametoprint);
    });
    Future token= SharedPrefrence().getToken();
    token.then((data) async {
      tokentoprint= data;
      print(tokentoprint);
    });
  }
  int counter ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(

          title: Text("Cash-Management"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          actions: [
            new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    counter = 0;
                  });
                }),
                counter != 0 ? new Positioned(
                  right: 11,
                  top: 11,
                  child: new Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    ),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 14,
                      minHeight: 14,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "  ${widget.notification.length} ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 8,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ) : new Container()
              ],
            ),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                          new SettingPage()));
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 120,
                  child: Column(

                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Profile",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Name:${widget.user_name}",
                        // "  ${widget.username} ",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      // Text(
                      //   "  ${widget.notification.length} ",),
                      // Text(" ${nametoprint} "),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

Container(
  color: Colors.lightBlue,
  height: 400,
  child:   ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.notification == null ?  0 : widget.notification.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        final count = widget.notification ;
                   print(count.length);
        return Card(

            color: Colors.blue,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        new DetailPage()));
              },
              child: Column(
                children:<Widget>[
Text('Amount'),
               ListTile(
                 title: Text(widget.notification[index] ["data"]["amount"].toString()),
                 subtitle: Text(widget.notification[index]["data"]["message"].toString()),
                  )  ,
                 Text('Created at '),

                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(widget.notification[index] ["created_at"].toString()),
                  ),
Text('updated at'),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(widget.notification[index] ["updated_at"].toString()),
                  ),
          ],
              ),
            ),
        );
      }),
),

            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 130,
              child: Button()
            ),
          ],
        ),

        // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        //   print("Increment Counter");
        //   setState(() {
        //     counter++;
        //   });
        // }, child: Icon(Icons.add),),
      ),
    );


  }

}
```

response_model.dart

```
class UserDetails {
  int userId;
  String userName;
  String apiToken;
  List<Notifications> notifications;

  UserDetails({this.userId, this.userName, this.apiToken, this.notifications});

  UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['user_id'];
    userName = json['user_name'];
    apiToken = json['api_token'];
    if (json['notifications'] != null) {
      notifications = new List<Notifications>();
      json['notifications'].forEach((v) {
        notifications.add(new Notifications.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['user_id'] = this.userId;
    data['user_name'] = this.userName;
    data['api_token'] = this.apiToken;
    if (this.notifications != null) {
      data['notifications'] =
          this.notifications.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Notifications {
  String id;
  String type;
  int notifiableId;
  String notifiableType;
  Data data;
  Null readAt;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Notifications(
      {this.id,
        this.type,
        this.notifiableId,
        this.notifiableType,
        this.data,
        this.readAt,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt});

  Notifications.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    type = json['type'];
    notifiableId = json['notifiable_id'];
    notifiableType = json['notifiable_type'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
    readAt = json['read_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['notifiable_id'] = this.notifiableId;
    data['notifiable_type'] = this.notifiableType;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    data['read_at'] = this.readAt;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int paymentId;
  String generatePaymentId;
  String message;
  int amount;

  Data({this.paymentId, this.generatePaymentId, this.message, this.amount});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    paymentId = json['payment_id'];
    generatePaymentId = json['generate_payment_id'];
    message = json['message'];
    amount = json['amount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['payment_id'] = this.paymentId;
    data['generate_payment_id'] = this.generatePaymentId;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    data['amount'] = this.amount;
    return data;
  }
}
```

It will be helpful if anyone let e know how to show detail page from this section.

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.notification == null ?  0 : widget.notification.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        final count = widget.notification ;
                   print(count.length);
        return Card(

            color: Colors.blue,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        new DetailPage()));
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `widget.user_name`, `widget.api_token` in HomePage, and pass it to Details Page.

**Home Page**

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (BuildContext context) =>
         new DetailPage(userName :widget.user_name, apiToken: widget.api_token)));
```

Comment: It's not working brother. I also tried with setting a constructor in detail page with userName, apiToken. Do you have a solution . It will be helpful if you edit some code in my page. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be used globally in your application, perhaps you can fetch your data from API before MaterialApp() so that your data can be used globally.

Other way is you can pass your UserDetails() data to next page by calling them inside your Navigator.push(). You can read more detail example [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)